# SQL Server : inner join with multiple ANDs and ORs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Each product has a `LatLng`. Over time, sometimes products can be duplicated but it is difficult to spot. The price or images may be slightly different.

I want to compare `Products` by their `ProductType` and their `Price` in each location and put them on a map so duplicates can be found more easily.

For each product I calculate 5% of its price so I can then add/subtract this from other Product prices to find rough matches.

`Products`

| ProductID | ProductType | Price | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Red Widget | 500 | 12.34 | 67.89 |
| DEF | Red Widget | 505 | 12.34 | 67.89 |
| MNO | Red Widget | 480 | 12.34 | 67.89 |
| RST | Red Widget | 500 | 12.34 | 67.89 |
| UVW | Red Widget | 300 | 12.34 | 67.89 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| JKL | Blue Widget | 800 | 76.54 | 32.10 |
| XYZ | Blue Widget | 800 | 45.67 | 23.45 |

The expected result is that `ABC`, `DEF`, `MNO` AND `RST` should be returned because they are all `Red Widgets`, are in the same location and are have either exactly the same price or prices within 5% of each other's price.

`UVW` is outside the percentage so likely not a duplicate and should not be returned.

`JKL` and `XYZ` are `Blue Widgets` with the same price, but not in the same location, and thus not returned.

**SQL**

This is what I have so far but it is returning far too many results. I think it's returning rows that are matching outside of each location. The ANDs in the JOIN look correct to me. It feels like the ORs may be allowing more flexibility in matching but the enclosing brackets look correct...

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        p.ProductID,
        p.ProductType,
        p.Price,
        (p.Price / 100) * 5 AS PricePercent,
        ROUND(p.Latitude, 3) AS Latitude,
        ROUND(p.Longitude, 3) AS Longitude
    FROM 
        Products p
    WHERE
       p.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND p.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.ProductID,
    a.Price,
    a.Latitude, a.Longitude
FROM 
    cte a
INNER JOIN 
    /* ProductIDs don't match */
    cte b ON a.ProductID <> b.ProductID
    /* match only where location is the same*/
          AND a.Latitude = b.Latitude 
          AND a.Longitude = b.Longitude
    /* match only where Product Type is the same*/
          AND a.ProductType = b.ProductType
    /*match only if price is the same, or within 5% above or 5% below price*/
          AND (/*same price*/
               b.Price = a.Price 
               OR
               /*b.price is within percentage over a.price*/
               (b.Price > a.Price AND b.Price < (a.Price+a.PricePercent))
               OR
               /*b.price is within percentage under a.price */
               (b.Price < a.Price AND b.Price >(a.Price-a.PricePercent)))
```

Comment: OK, the `SELECT` in your CTE definition is incomplete - you're probably missing `WHERE (condition) ....` .

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY` in the outer query when you have no aggregation?

Comment: Also i really suggest better aliasing. "C" is for "Product" but "A" and "B" are for "CTE"? In my dictionary "P" is for "Product" and "C" is for "CTE" (though you would have to give the 2 instances of the CTE different aliases).

Comment: Then why not use `DISTINCT`? Having a `GROUP BY` clause implies aggregation, and you have none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this thing:

```sql
AND (/*same price*/
                   b.Price = a.Price 
                   OR
                   /*b.price is within percentage over a.price*/
                   (b.Price > a.Price AND b.Price < (a.Price+a.PricePercent))
                   OR
                   /*b.price is within percentage under a.price */
                   (b.Price < a.Price AND b.Price >(a.Price-a.PricePercent))
           )
```

Is (or should be) the same as this:

```sql
AND (
    -- price within range +/- percent
    b.Price < (a.Price+a.PricePercent) 
    AND b.Price >(a.Price-a.PricePercent)
    )
```

And second for me it works:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e2e05/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

Query 1:

```
WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
            p.ProductID,
            p.ProductType,
            p.Price,
            (p.Price / 100) * 5 AS PricePercent,
            ROUND(p.Latitude, 3) AS Latitude,
            ROUND(p.Longitude, 3) AS Longitude
        FROM 
            Products p
        WHERE
           p.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND p.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
    )
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT a.ProductID,
        a.Price,
        a.Latitude, a.Longitude
    FROM 
        cte a
    INNER JOIN 
        /* ProductIDs don't match */
        cte b ON a.ProductID <> b.ProductID
        /* match only where location is the same*/
              AND a.Latitude = b.Latitude 
              AND a.Longitude = b.Longitude
        /* match only where Product Type is the same*/
              AND a.ProductType = b.ProductType
        /*match only if price is the same, or within 5% above or 5% below price*/
              AND (
        -- price within range +/- percent
        b.Price < (a.Price+a.PricePercent) 
        AND b.Price >(a.Price-a.PricePercent)
     )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e2e05/3/0)**:

| ProductID | Price | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 500 | 12 | 68 |
| DEF | 505 | 12 | 68 |
| RST | 500 | 12 | 68 |